# Помогите с байтами!

Tags: python, tkinter, byte, байты

Я сделал программу на питоне чтобы можно было текст конвертировать в байты и наоборот...
Я сделал его при помощи ткинтера!

```
def shifrate():
    encoded = bytes(Text1.get(1.0, END), 'utf-8') #Текст1 это поле которое будет конвертироваться
    Text2.delete(1.0, END) #Поле где будет конвертированный текст
    Text2.insert(1.0, encoded)
```

когда я ввожу "Привет" то мне в поле пишет "ÐŸÑ€Ð¸Ð²ÐµÑ‚!", как его обратно вернуть в строку или в байты?
или в такой вид: `b'\xd0\xbf\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82!\n'`

Comment: В общем случае никак, делая Text2.insert, вы делате обратное и некорректное преобразование байтов в текст, в процессе которого некоторые байты вполне могут потеряться

Comment: А чтобы получить "такой вид", делайте repr(encoded)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
_encoded = bytes("Привет", 'utf-8')
print(_encoded)          # b'\xd0\x9f\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82'
 
text = _encoded.decode()
print(text)              # Привет
```

Comment: Только вот ткинтер всё испортит